# Regarding OpenGL driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, opengl

I have some problems with installing the OpenGL driver.

I have the [NVIDIA Geforce GT 630M](http://www.nvidia.in/object/geforce-gt-630m-in.html#pdpContent=2) graphics card, but when I run my programs, i get the following error:

> Unable to create OpenGL 3.3 context (flags 0, profile 1)

On the website, it says that I should be capable of using OpenGL up to 4.1. (But currently it can only support OpenGL up to 3.1.)

Whenever I try to download drivers I get errors. I tried downloading [this driver](http://developer.nvidia.com/opengl-driver), but I get this error when I try installing it:

> NVIDIA installation program could not continue.
>
> This graphics driver could not find a compatible graphics device.

Comment: Try a driver from here: http://www.nvidia.com/object/notebook_drivers.html

Comment: I have already tried this one, but it doesn't seem to improve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved nVidia OpenGL compatibility problems using [GLView](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/download.php).  It will help you to identify any compliance issues you have with your driver and also facilitate updating drivers.

Comment: I have downloaded GLView now, and according to the program I am using Intel(R) HD Graphics Family. I tried downloading the driver for this (http://downloadcenter.intel.com/confirm.aspx?httpDown=http://downloadmirror.intel.com/21430/a08/Win7_64_152612.exe&lang=eng&Dwnldid=21430&DownloadType=Drivers&ProductID=3319&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Processor+graphics&ProductProduct=2nd+Generation+Intel%C2%AE+Core%E2%84%A2+Processors+with+Intel%C2%AE+HD+Graphics+3000%2f2000) but it says it's not compatible.

Comment: I figured out how to get and install the latest driver, but it says the latest driver is already installed. But according to GLView, it isn't. I get this message from GLView:
"
OpenGL driver version check (Current: 3.1.0 - Build 8.15.10.2418, Latest known: 8.17.13.142):
Outdated version of display drivers detected
According the database, you are might be not using the latest version of display drivers for your video card."

Comment: Ah, then your notebook (I assume) is actually using the on-board video card and not your actual NVIDIA GPU. Just check your manual to find out how to switch between the two.